Expectation out the inner product
We define on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{X}$ with respective Borel probability measures $p$ and $q$. Let $f$ and $g$ be a function in $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}$.
My question: Under what conditions can the expectation be taken outside the inner product? In other words, under what conditions does the following equality hold:
$$\langle \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p}[f(x,\cdot )], \mathbb{E}_{y \sim q}[g(y,\cdot)] \rangle_{\mathcal{X}} = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p} \mathbb{E}_{y \sim q} \langle f(x,\cdot ), g(y,\cdot) \rangle_{\mathcal{X}}?$$

I’m confused, $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p} [f(x)]$ is not an element of $\mathcal{X}$ but $\mathbb{R}$? Or maybe I don’t know this notation.

@julio_es_sui_glace sorry. It is my bad. Maybe I should modify my question but in general, I mean, I am considering the condition to take expectation out the inner product

Maybe you are confused with the scalar product defined on Variables that have a moment of order 2?  Is your question: $E(f(x)E(f(y)) =E_x((E_y \langle f(x),f(y) \rangle ) )$?

@julio_es_sui_glace coucou, I recently modified my question. Is it better ?

No the problem is the arrival set of the Esperance

Sorry, I don't understand what you mean ? @julio_es_sui_glace

Try an example to figure it out

You have two random variables $X$, $Y$. Do you want to know when the equality $\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle\right) = \left\langle \mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X\right),\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(Y\right)\right\rangle$  holds?

@framago yes, in case X follows distribution p and Y follows distribution q

Let $\left(\mathcal X,\left\langle\cdot,\cdot\right\rangle\right)$ be a separable Hilbert space, so that we have an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two $\mathcal X$-valued random variables. We'll show that $$\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle\right)=\left\langle \mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(X\right),\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(Y\right)\right\rangle.$$
Using linearity of the expectation and the properties of the inner product, we get
\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle\right) &=
\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\left\langle X,\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle e_m\right\rangle\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left\langle X, \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle e_m\right\rangle\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left\langle X,  e_m\right\rangle\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\right)
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\left\langle X,  e_m\right\rangle\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\right)
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left\langle X,e_m\right\rangle\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\right)
.
\end{align}
Taking the expectation wrt $X$, we get
\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle\right) &=\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left\langle X,e_m\right\rangle\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\right)\right)
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(\left\langle X,e_m\right\rangle\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\right)\right)
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(\left\langle X,e_m\right\rangle\right)\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\right)
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(\left\langle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle e_n,e_m\right\rangle\right)\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\right)
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\langle  \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle e_n,e_m\right\rangle\right)\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\right)
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\left\langle   e_n,e_m\right\rangle\right)\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\right)
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\delta_{n,m}\right)\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\right)
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(\left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right)\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\overline{\left\langle Y,e_n\right\rangle}\right)
\end{align}
Now we compute the other side of our identity
\begin{align}
\left\langle \mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(X\right),\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(Y\right)\right\rangle&=\left\langle    \mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle e_n\right),\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle e_m\right)\right\rangle
\\&=\left\langle    \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right) e_n,\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left( \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle\right) e_m\right\rangle
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\biggl\langle    \mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right) e_n,\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left( \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle\right) e_m\biggr\rangle
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right)\overline{\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left( \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle\right)}\left\langle e_n, e_m\right\rangle
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right)\overline{\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left( \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle\right)}\delta_{n,m}
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right)\overline{\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left( \left\langle Y,e_n\right\rangle\right)}
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E_x}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right)\mathop{\mathbb E_y}\left( \overline{\left\langle Y,e_n\right\rangle}\right),
\end{align}
where the last equality holds because the conjugate of the expectation is equal to the expectation of the conjugate. So we are done.

Yes, now, I agree with you. So we don't need the condition of independence right ?

Exactly! You will need that only to establish $\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle\right) = \left\langle \mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X\right),\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(Y\right)\right\rangle$

That's what I wrote on my draft when I read your first solution.

Thank you very much for your time

Always glad to help!

haha it is also the first time I knew about the chat function on math stack exchange. Many thanks.

But do you think that we need to add conditions to make sure that $E_[\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty] X_i = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} E(X)$ because we are using the linearity inifinite summation

Let $\left(\mathcal X,\left\langle\cdot,\cdot\right\rangle\right)$ be a separable Hilbert space, so that we have an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two $\mathcal X$-valued random variables. We will show that, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $$\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle\right) = \left\langle \mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X\right),\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(Y\right)\right\rangle.$$Using linearity of the expectation and the properties of the inner product, we get
\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle\right) &=
\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle e_n,\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle e_m\right\rangle\right)
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\left\langle e_n,e_m\right\rangle\right)
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\overline{\left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle}\delta_{n,m}\right)
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\overline{\left\langle Y,e_n\right\rangle}\right),
\end{align}
while, on the other hand, we have
\begin{align}
\left\langle \mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X\right),\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(Y\right)\right\rangle&=\left\langle    \mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle e_n\right),\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle e_m\right)\right\rangle
\\&=\left\langle    \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right) e_n,\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle\right) e_m\right\rangle
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\biggl\langle    \mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right) e_n,\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle\right) e_m\biggr\rangle
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right)\overline{\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle\right)}\left\langle e_n, e_m\right\rangle
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right)\overline{\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle Y,e_m\right\rangle\right)}\delta_{n,m}
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right)\overline{\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle Y,e_n\right\rangle\right)}
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right)\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \overline{\left\langle Y,e_n\right\rangle}\right),
\end{align}
where the last equality holds because the conjugate of the expectation is equal to the expectation of the conjugate.
If the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so are the random variables $\left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle$ and $\overline{\left\langle Y,e_n\right\rangle}$, thus
$$\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\overline{\left\langle Y,e_n\right\rangle}\right)=\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \left\langle X,e_n\right\rangle\right)\mathop{\mathbb E}\left( \overline{\left\langle Y,e_n\right\rangle}\right),$$
and the following holds $\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle\right) = \left\langle \mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X\right),\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(Y\right)\right\rangle$.

Thank you for answer. I wonder if it works in the case when the dimensions of Hilbert space is infinite

It does hold even if the dimension of the Hilbert space is infinite, as long as it is separable (i.e. there is a countable orthonormal basis). I am not sure if it holds also if the space is not separable, because then every orthonormal basis would be uncountable.

Besides, when you used the expectation notation, could you please elaborate further?
For example, on the LHS, does it mean you are taking the expectation under the joint distribution, or is it as I described in my question?
I sincerely apologize for bothering you, but honestly, I am new to this field.

Yes, I agree with you but normally we will work will the Hilbert space which is separable.

When you take the expectation of the product of two random variables, you need to take it wrt the joint distribution. But if they are independent, you can separately take the expectation of both $X$ and $Y$ wrt their own distributions and then multiply them, because $\mathop{\mathbb E}(XY)=\mathop{\mathbb E}(X)\mathop{\mathbb E}(Y)$.

Obviously, you can generalize it to functions of independent variables. If $X$ and $Y$ are indepedent, so are $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$. Hence we can write $\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\left\langle f(X),g(Y)\right\rangle\right) = \left\langle \mathop{\mathbb E}\left(f(X)\right),\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(g(Y)\right)\right\rangle$.

I know but in my question, I think I am considering a different one like E_{x}E_{y}<...>.  I mean we take the expectation w.r.t Y first and then in X

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
